# error 2501 access vba

Tags: ms-access, vba

When I run this code, I get "The Open Form action was canceled" with an error code of 2501 The line it gets caught on when I debug is the DoCmd.RunSQL (Req)

```
Function Compare()
    Dim oDB As DAO.Database   
    Dim oRst As DAO.Recordset
    Dim nbligne As Long
    Dim Req As String
    Dim default As String
    Dim tables As String
    Dim table
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim champ As String
    Dim j As Integer

    Set oDB = CurrentDb
    Set oRst = oDB.OpenRecordset("SELECT Count(*) FROM CELLCAC;")
    nbligne = oRst.Fields(0).Value
    Set oRs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("CELLCAC")
    Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set fldr = fs.getfolder("C:\Users\Documents\Application\Application_vba\Delta")
    Set fls = fldr.files
    Set fld = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("TABLES_A_VERIFIER_DEFAULT")

    For Each fl In fls
        If fl Like "*.txt" Then
            source = Left(fl.Name, Len(fl.Name) - 4)
            tables = source
            default = "DEFAULT_" & tables
            table = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(default)
            For i = 0 To table.Count - 1
                champ = table(i).Name
                Req = "INSERT INTO DELTA_DEFAULT(BSCNAME, CELLNAME, MO, PARAMETRE ,DEFAULT ,RESEAU)" _
                & "select DISTINCT  [" & tables & "]![BSCNAME], [" & tables & "]![CELLNAME],('" & tables & "'), ('" & champ & "')  ,[" & default & "]![" & champ & "],[" & tables & "]![" & champ & "] " _
                & " from (" & tables & ")  INNER join (" & default & ") on ( " & default & ".Zone = " & tables & ".Zone ) " _
                & " Where [" & default & "]![" & champ & "] <> [" & tables & "]![" & champ & "];"
               DoCmd.RunSQL (Req)
            Next i
        End If
    Next fl
End Function
```

Comment: Post what the sql value is in 'Req' when you try the DoCmd.

Comment: You reported the error message references Open Form, but your code doesn't mention a form.  Suggest you test that VBA procedure in isolation from any form events.  At least then Access may give you an error message which better describes the problem with the `INSERT` statement.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing : DoCmd.RunSQL (Req),

can you try : `oDB.Execute (Req)`

I had several issues and this helps me a lot !

Answer (score 0):

From the first line of your `req` query to the second line, you need to add a space character.

I believe that currently the query will not recognise the word `SELECT` if it is joined to the closed bracket.

```
Req = "INSERT INTO DELTA_DEFAULT(BSCNAME, CELLNAME, MO, PARAMETRE,DEFAULT ,RESEAU)" _ 
& " select
```

In addition; from what I understood I would have used the `VALUES` clause when creating an `INSERT INTO` statement. Perhaps:

```
Req = "INSERT INTO DELTA_DEFAULT(BSCNAME, CELLNAME, MO, PARAMETRE ,DEFAULT ,RESEAU)" _
                & " VALUES (select DISTINCT  [" & tables & "]![BSCNAME], [" & tables & "]![CELLNAME],('" & tables & "'), ('" & champ & "')  ,[" & default & "]![" & champ & "],[" & tables & "]![" & champ & "] " _
                & " from (" & tables & ")  INNER join (" & default & ") on ( " & default & ".Zone = " & tables & ".Zone ) " _
                & " Where [" & default & "]![" & champ & "] <> [" & tables & "]![" & champ & "]);"
```